# GUI does not show after creating executable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyinstaller

I would like to use PandasGui to show intermediate DataFrame results of my app. It works perfectly in Jupyter. However, once I create the executable (using PyInstaller) the app does not work - just cmd shows for a second. Generaly I have no problem with other GUIs after converting to exe (EasyGUI, tkinter, etc.). So this must be something very specific.

Any ideas how to make it work?
Or any alternative to PandasGui which works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly was the pyinstaller command that you tried for compiling the executable?

Also, you may want to consider tkinter or PyQt5 if this problem persists and you're unable to get a solution here since at least the former has worked for you in the past.

Comment: Just this: 
pyinstaller myfile.py. Well tkinter would work. But I really like the PandasGui. It works for any DF without any adjustments and also shows some basic statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use some of the pyinstaller optional arguments for generating a onefile/folder executable bundle. Here's a few of the other options you may want to consider trying when running the command: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html